# RequestFileSystem alternative

Tags: javascript, storage, webapi

I use window.requestFileSystem to store video files and playing offline (like https://www.youtube.com/feed/downloads)

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, ...)
```

but as requestFileSystem is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem#browser_compatibility), how to store blob files correctly, which API could cover the same functionality?